# Ubuntu 20.04 may have common issue of gnome-panel and album art that causes laptop to freeze

Tags: 20.04, freeze, gnome-panel

I hope this isn't my being a numpty, but if I am ... :-)

My laptop for the past maybe year regularly freezes - this can happen several times in a day, or it can last days without freezing.

I replaced the hard drive, reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04, and have updated the kernel regularly (currently on 5.15.5). I also run gnome flashback (i.e. with "old fashioned" menus ...!).

I have tried reverting to the standard Ubuntu interface, but the freezes still happen.

I have been checking the journalctl logs to try to see if there is a common error just before the reboot.

One line does seem to occur either immediately before or very close to when the laptop freezes (although REISUB is enabled, it doesn't work in the freeze, and a power cycle is the only option):-

```
gnome-panel[2737]: unable to fetch album art: Operation not supported
```

If this isn't the cause, it would be nice to eliminate it - unless there are other ways to identify potential issues!

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: 5.15 is not a supported kernel on 20.04. How did you update to it? Based on your description, it seems you're also installing a lot of other things to manipulate the desktop environment that are not in repos and aren't in system settings. If I had to guess at a problem, it's probably one or more of these choices.  Do your issues persist in a live session?  How about a clean install?  If you don't like the way that GNOME is designed (I don't blame you) have you considered trying a different flavor? That's probably better than making offspec changes to your UI that might be causing it to freeze